# Powershell script- Configure Permission to Access CRM API

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a Powershell that can Register an application in Azure Active Directory. But I am unable to find script for configuring this app to access CRM APIs. I am referring to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603747.aspx)
 Any pointers are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [New-AzureADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) to grant permission. Like below:

```
$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris $appURI -Homepage $appHomePageUrl -ReplyUrls $appReplyURLs -PasswordCredentials $PasswordCredential -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph
```

This [blog](https://www.mavention.nl/create-azure-ad-app-registration-with-powershell-part-2/) will be helpful.

You also could give permission on Azure Portal.

[image]

Please refer to this [link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/abhinavranjandynamics365/archive/2017/08/23/online-management-api-setting-up-access-through-azure-ad).